# Multiplot in GNU Plot with pm3d

Tags: gnuplot

I have an issue with multiplot in pm3d. I have a script which plots one surface but when I set multiplot, it says xrange is out of range:
Here is my code:

```
set terminal png size 2000,1600 enhanced transparent
set encoding utf8 #iso_8859_1
set output 'output.png'

#---------------#
#  Canvas style #
#---------------#
set border linewidth 2
set pm3d border lw 2

#-------------------------------------------#
#  Set the Axis and Axis-Labels Formatting  #
#-------------------------------------------#

### Set xtics below ###
set xtics font "Helvetica,26" scale 3 # Font for xtics
set xtics offset 3,-1.5 # Put xtics away from the axis

### Set ytics below ###
set ytics font "Helvetica,26" scale 3
set ytics offset 3,0 # Put ytics away from the axis

### Set ztics below ###
set ztics font "Helvetica,26" scale 3
set ztics 5 # Difference between numbers on Y-axis
set format z "" # To hide ztics on the left side

set grid # Show gridlines on both axis
set pm3d interpolate 3,3 # Lines on points. Smoothness of the points
unset key # Show no key

#------------------#
#  Plot the Graph  #
#------------------#

splot "plastoquinone-scan-a1-formatted.txt" with pm3d

#----------------#
#  Set Multiplot #
#----------------#
#set multiplot layout 2,2
#plot "++" "plastoquinone-scan-a1-formatted.txt" with pm3d
#plot "++" "plastoquinone-scan-a2-formatted.txt" with pm3d
```

The data files are quite long so I uploaded them on github.
Here are the links please:
https://github.com/i4hashmi/Scans/blob/master/plastoquinone-scan-a1-formatted.txt
https://github.com/i4hashmi/Scans/blob/master/plastoquinone-scan-a2-formatted.txt

I need these graphs for my PhD thesis. Help will be appreciated a lot.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting multiplot *after* the first plot? Also, splot, not plot.

Comment: ... and only `"plastoquinone-scan-a1-formatted.txt"` without `"++"`

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. It solved that problem. Now there is another problem with multiplot but it  is a separate thing so I am posting it as a new question.